# chromatic polynomial of chordal graph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

Let $G$ bei a chordal Graph. What is the chromatic polynomial of $G$?

My own research on this lead me to a conference paper, "chromatic polynomials of chordal graphs" by Chandrasekharan, Madhavan and Laskar, which I cannot find online, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a chordal graph.
The important property we need is, that $G$ has a simplicial elimination sequence.

Suppose you want to know the number of $k$-colorings of $G$.
Let $v$ be a simplicial vertex of degree $d$.
For every $k$-coloring of $G-v$ the neighbours of $v$ have $d$ different colors,
so for $v$ there are $k-d$ colors left to choose from.
This gives you a very easy recursive procedure to determine the chromatic polynomial
of $G$ as a product of linear factors.